# Total rows number on Acumatica Webservice?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, acumatica

i'm working with acumatica 6.0 WebServices, i know how to get top by top inventory rows, but i donw know if exist some way to get the total rows number,  and some way to get the last inventoryID too, i read the documentation of webservices but not exist some example like this.

some one could you help me with this logic? or the only way to get that number is creating a new screen with that info and explode it with webservice?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to get total number of records in Acumatica via the API. Since records are always returned by API in ascending order by key fields and there is no option to change default behavior, it doesn't seem possible to request only last record either.

Could you please provide additional details about your scenario? Do you really need to request number of all inventory items from Acumatica? How are you going to use this number further in your integration?

Comment: I just have the idea for create a paginated view about the total items of the inventory, so, that is the reason about why i want the last item and the total number of rows, nothing's special only i wanted to know if exist that way with the API, thank you Ruslan.

Comment: One big purpose of knowing how many total records to expect is to display a progress bar to the end user so they know (a.)that the program is working and (b.)how much longer they can expect it to take. The OP's pagination purpose is closely related: showing that they are on page 18 out of a total of 376, for example; and if they want to jump straight to the last page, they can provide a link to jump straight there without having to walk through all the intervening pages. I too am in desperate need of this functionality, as Acumatica takes a long time to send everything.